# How do I get the current directory in a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, iis

I am using System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() to get the current directory in my web service, but that does not give me the current directory. How do I get the current directory in a web service?

Thanks
Stuart

Comment: Where are you hosting the web service? IIS? Are you using WCF

Answer (score 50):

In a webservice, you are running in a http context. So,

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/")
```

will give you the answer.

Comment: This maps to the root. Which *may not* be current

Answer (score 33):

You can use

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

This gives you the root directory of your application.

Comment: this is the one

Answer (score 23):

`HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".")` will give you the current working directory.

But to Rohan West's comment about potentially being outside of an HttpContext it would probably be better to just call:

```
HostingEnvironment.MapPath(".")
```

See details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944219/what-is-the-difference-between-server-mappath-and-hostingenvironment-mappath)

Answer (score 21):

HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/") maps back to the root of the application or virtual directory.

HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/")  <-- ROOT
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".")  <-- CURRENT DIRECTORY
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("..")  <-- PARENT DIRECTORY

All the above is relative, so you can you any combination to traverse the directory tree.

Answer (score 12):

Best way is using

`HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath` under `System.Web.Hosting`

for more information please refer [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

`HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/")` would get you the root of the application?

Which is plenty most likely as you probably know the path from there.

Another option which might be of interest:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Directory/")
```

This builds from the root of the application no matter what.

Without the first slash this will take directory from where you call as the start:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Directory/")
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("..") [observe two(..) dots instead of (.)] gives physical directory of Virtual Directory of the site!