# What is the difference between Server.MapPath and HostingEnvironment.MapPath?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any difference between `Server.MapPath()` and `HostingEnvironment.MapPath()`? Does `Server.MapPath()` have any advantages over `HostingEnvironment.MapPath()`?

My original problem was mapping the file path on a server when the `HttpContext` is not present and I cannot pass a `Server` variable from `Global.asax` to my method.

I used `HostingEnvironment.MapPath()` instead since it doesn't need `HttpContext`. Are there any situations when these two methods will give different results?

Comment: Related post - [Server.MapPath("."), Server.MapPath("~"), Server.MapPath(@"\"), Server.MapPath("/"). What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/275781/465053)

Answer (score 219, accepted):

`Server.MapPath()` eventually calls `HostingEnvironment.MapPath()`, but it creates a `VirtualPath` object with specific options:

> The `VirtualPath` object passed to `HostingEnvironment.MapPath()` is constructed like this:
>
> ```
> VirtualPath.Create(path, VirtualPathOptions.AllowAllPath|VirtualPathOptions.AllowNull);
> ```

***Edit***: in reality, the only difference is that you are allowed to pass null to `Server.MapPath()`, but not to `HostingEnvironment.MapPath()`

Comment: So I will always get same results from both methods, right? (excluding null argument)

Comment: **TL;DR**: always use `HostingEnvironment.MapPath()` to keep sanity. (+1)

Comment: There must be something different beyond null because `Server.MapPath("myFolder")` works fine but to get the same result with HostingEnvironment, I had to use `HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/myFolder")`.

Comment: Fantastic answer for initiating an ftp session via a call to a web service. Saved me huge today!!!

Comment: Actually there is another difference - relative paths (e.g. Image/pict.png) are not allowed with HostingEnvironment.MapPath.

Answer (score 120):

`Server.MapPath()` requires an `HttpContext`. `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` does not.

Comment: but both require `System.Web` so will they work with Self Hosted OWIN environments?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any situations when these two methods will give different results?

In WCF service, because of the `null` `HttpContext.Current`, you can't get the path by `Server.MapPath()` and will get a `HttpException`, but you can get the path by `HostingEnvironment.MapPath()`.

```cs
// This will get a Http Exception
string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("myPath");
// This will get your path
string path = System.Web.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/myPath");
```

Reference:

- [`HttpServerUtility.MapPath(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath?view=netframework-4.8)
- [WCF services and ASP.NET - WCF | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-services-and-aspnet)
- [c# - How to MapPath with RequestContext in WCF Service - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384894/how-to-mappath-with-requestcontext-in-wcf-service)