# How to programmatically find an ASP.NET App_Data folder path

Tags: asp.net

I need to read a file there. I tried Assembly.ExecutingAssembly etc but that doesnt work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - Find Absolute Path to the App_Data folder from Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268738/asp-net-mvc-find-absolute-path-to-the-app-data-folder-from-controller)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From asp.net it's simple:

```
Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");//anywhere
```

Comment: Except sometimes it's not. Deployed websites often have their App_Data in `~/bin/App_Data`, but use `~/App_Data` locally. Using the `|DataDirectory|` substitution is broken in these cases. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706945/datadirectory-returns-wrong-path-to-appdata-folder

Comment: @CharlesBurns fixed, see at your question

Comment: I'm doing so in some cs class and the Server object was giving problems.
HttpContext.Current.Server made it work.

Comment: @ozn is not common these days to use App_Data, except azure is using it to put Webjobs. Another question is the App_Data could be in bin directory as CharlesBurns metioned

Answer (score 12):

another way is:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory");
```

Comment: This isn't documented on MSDN, so I would not recommend using this

Answer (score 4):

**`String base = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;`** 
//Using above code , you will get base directory of your applications.
`String pathToData_App = base + "/App_Data/SqLite.db"`;

Above code works for me.

Comment: best answer so far. This one does the job. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to execute ELMAH scripts for AppData so is used this

```
var elmahScript = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "ELMAH-1.2-db-SQLServer.sql");
```