# download link give me filenotfound exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, download

in my controller, this is the code i have

```
   public FileResult Download(string file)
    {



        var vFullFileName = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/Files/");

        var files = uploadedfileRepository.AllIncluding();
        string filename = (from f in files

                           select f.FileName).First();


        return File(Path.Combine(vFullFileName, filename), "application/csv", filename);
    }
```

I put the breakpoint and the file point to the right directory, but why still give me File not found exception?

and in my view this is what i have

```
 <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { id = item.FileName})
        </td
```

Comment: `App_Data` is a protected directory, you can not use it for direct download.

Comment: App_Data can be accessed and used for storing anything. There is no public access from browser but your controller can have address to it. Make sure the file is there.

Comment: can you point out whats wrong with my code i will greatly appreaciate it

Comment: if I understand well, ether place your file in other directory, ether use a handler that fully reads it and send it.

Comment: well, path.combine fulls reads it but i dont know the send part too well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `action` method have a parameter with name **file**. But your are HTML will have a parameter/ query string called  **id**, instead od file, So change your view code to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { file= item.FileName})
```

Also to get the path, try this

```
string fullFilePath=Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"),filename)
return File(fullFilePath,"application/csv",filename);
```

Comment: hey Shyju, thanks for reply, even i change the data type to file, the same exception still hangs there

Comment: check this answer to get the correct way to get path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268738/asp-net-mvc-find-absolute-path-to-the-app-data-folder-from-controller

Comment: so the path instead using direct access to App_Data/Files, use server.mappath to access it, how about my parameter, can i leave it using "string file" ?

Comment: If you keep your parameter name as file in your action method ( that is what you have in your question), you need to call it with 'file` querystring. Use the ActionLink sample i wrote in my answer.

Comment: the exception still hangs there after i apply your method, i put the break point there and parameter "string file" show the file name and fullFilePath shows the whole full path, and exception still filenotfound, url somehow doesnt map to the link/dir

Comment: make sure the file has READ permission for IIS users/ ASP.NET

Comment: right click on folder, select security tab, edit/add users with relevant permissions

Answer (score 0):

`App_Data` is for database files that are accessed by MS SQL Server, and possibly your application's own data files (like a Lucene index).

IIS (and ASP.NET) are configured to block any client requests to that directory.

The solution is just to move the files to another directory. Just create a new folder in your site's root (say "CsvFiles") and link to that.

That said, why don't you serve up a HTTP 301 Redirection (or even a direct link) to the CSV files instead of serving them via your application?

UPDATE: This answer is incorrect because by serving the file contents via an MVC File response the user's browser doesn't acutally access the `App_Data` directory.

Comment: not really. you store things in App_data and then access it, if there is read, write access.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but how to approach the way for direction, any code suggest plz

Comment: any problem with my code tho, i understand app_data is protected property now, besides that, any problem that my code has ?

Comment: check if the file is there. is it there?

Comment: and yes. you are passing parameter but you are not doing anything with the parameter you pass in.

Comment: I am really stuck here. you are right, the parameter has nothing to do with it, how do i change it?