# Azure: Read files from App_Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have a certificate file which isn't for SSL, but for other purposes. It's located in App_Data folder. Is it possible to read this file when my web site deployed in Azure?

I tried this, but not working:

```
Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/cert.pfx);
```

Comment: There is another question around here which addresses the same issue, and the accepted answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1268755/1966937). However, please read the comments / other answers, since rumor has it that you have to slightly change the code. I hope this helps.