# ASP.Net vNext App_Data folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Similar question to the one found here: [ASP.NET MVC - Find Absolute Path to the App_Data folder from Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268738/asp-net-mvc-find-absolute-path-to-the-app-data-folder-from-controller).

Is `App_Data` folder gone? `Server.MapPath` seems to be gone too.

I tried to achieve the same results with `Url.Content`, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We do have `App_Data` in *vNext*.

This should still work

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString();
```

As for `Server.MapPath` equivalents you can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` and build your path from there.

You can also use the `IApplicationEnvironment` service

```
private readonly IApplicationEnvironment _appEnvironment;

public HomeController(IApplicationEnvironment appEnvironment)
{
    _appEnvironment = appEnvironment;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    var rootPath = _appEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath;
    return View();
}
```

`IHostingEnvironment` is the moral equivalent of the `IApplicationEnvironment` for **web applications**. For **PhysicalFileSystem**, `IHostingEnvironment` falls back to `IApplicationEnvironment`.

```
private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
    _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
   var rootPath = _hostingEnvironment.MapPath("APP_DATA");
   return View();
}
```

Comment: config.json as of vs2015 preview version is stored at project folder, i'm not sure if we can call that App_Data folder. I just found out that we can also use IHostingEnvironment.WebRoot within Startup class. will this be official best practice or still workaround?

Comment: It looks like they have changed it's location. IHostingEnvironment is the moral equivalent of the IApplicationEnvironment but for web applications. For PhysicalFileSystem, IHostingEnvironment falls back to IApplicationEnvironment.

Comment: string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString(); will not work on CoreCLR

Answer (score 4):

MapPath exists in IHostingEnvironment

```
private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;
public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    _env = env;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
   var dataFolderPath = _env.MapPath("APP_DATA");
   return View();
}
```