# PDFSharp saving pdf to Content folder in ASP .NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdfsharp

I'm new to PDFSharp and I'm trying to save a PDF document, but when I call `renderer.PdfDocument.Save(filename)` it attempts to save it inside `C:\Program Files\IIS Express\` and obviously it crashes out of denied permission.

How can I save the PDF document to /Content/ folder inside my MVC project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function like `Server.MapPath` to get the absolute path of the destination folder and pass that to the `Save` method.

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1268755/1015447