# how to create a file and insert json data to it in MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Hi i want to create file in MVC and insert JSON data into that file.
Folder location to create that file is

~/Content/File

please give any suggestion

Comment: show what you already try

Answer (score 2):

```
public FileResult SaveJsonDataToFile(string JsonString)
{
    #region " Set Path of File "
    // ASP.NET MVC4
    string FilePath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/File/jsondata.json");

    // ASP.NET MVC1 -> MVC3
    // use this HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/File/jsondata.json");

    // Ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268738/asp-net-mvc-find-absolute-path-to-the-app-data-folder-from-controller
    #endregion

    #region " Save Data to File "
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter FWriter = new StreamWriter(FilePath, true))
    {
        FWriter.Write(JsonString);
    }
    #endregion

    #region " Read File to FileData "
    byte[] FileData = null;
    FileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
    #endregion

    #region " Delete File "
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(FilePath))
        System.IO.File.Delete(FilePath);
    #endregion

    //  return if you need to send file to client
    return File(FileData, "text/json" /* i don't sure for json file mimetype */);
}
```

this example code is C# .Net MVC

hope this help !

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
public class Countries {
 public string Country {  get;  set; }
 public string CountryCode {  get;  set; }
 public string Currency {  get;  set; }
 public string CurrencyCode {  get;  set; }
}
List < Countries > _country = new List < Countries > ();
_country.Add(new Countries() Country = "Pakistan",
 CountryCode = "PK",
 Currency = "Rupee",
 Code = "PKR"
};

string fileContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(country);

OR

string fileContent = @ "[ {
'Country': 'Nigeria',
'CountryCode': 'NG',
'Currency': 'Naira',
'Code': 'NGN'
}, {
'Country': 'Pakistan',
'CountryCode': 'PK',
'Currency': 'Rupee',
'Code': 'PKR'
}]";

string filePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/File/jsondata.json");
try {
 if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
  System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
 var W = new StreamWriter(filePath);
 W.WriteLine(fileContent);
 W.Close();

} catch (Exception e) {
 Console.WriteLine(e);
 throw;
}
```

Comment: To improve your answer maybe you can beautify the code and check again