# Partial view load image not displayed

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, image

I implemented a PartialView Load but the (img tag) is not displayed an image.
There was no error and the alt="IMAGE" was displayed instead.

**Home/Index.cshtml**

```
<div id="partialviews">
</div>

<script type="text/jscript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#partialviews").load('/home/GetImage');
});
</script>
```

**Home/HomeController.cs**

```
public PartialViewResult GetImage(string category)
{
    return PartialView("_ShowImage");
}
```

**_ShowImage.cshtml**

```
<div>
    @Html.Label("Image:")
    @{ var imagePath = @"~/Images/cctv.jpg"; }
    <div>
        <img scr="@Url.Content(@imagePath)" alt="IMAGE" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[Project directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yb9U.png)

Comment: can you show your folder structure of your project containing the partial view and image?

Comment: May be this answer from an another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1268755/5918240) can help you.

Comment: `App_Data` is a special folder (used for data such as database files) and will not render out any contents on the web. Place you images in the `Images` folder

Comment: I moved the jpg to Images folder but still the image is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
<div>
    <img scr="~/Images/cctv.jpg" alt="IMAGE" />
</div>
```

If this does not work, the image path is not correct.
And check, if the folder Images is included to your project.

Comment: I took out the ~ in front of the imagePath and it works now!  It is a new Visual Studio 2017 project with .NET 4.5.2;  I used ~ before and it has no problem til now.  Any idea why?

Comment: Did the folder infrastructure change?

Comment: No, folder infrastructure is the same as posted earlier.