# how to get the application path in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to get the application path ?  bin path

in asp.net

thank's in advance

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10951599/465053).

Comment: Another post which talks about [server map paths in web applications in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/275781/465053)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Gets the ASP.NET application's virtual application root path on the server.**

```
Request.ApplicationPath;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.applicationpath.aspx

```
ResolveUrl("~/bin");
```

Answer (score 40):

```
Server.MapPath("~/bin")
```

You could also use the [HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.applicationphysicalpath.aspx) property.

Comment: Use this if you don't have request available, like I just didn't. Great answer.

Answer (score 20):

I needed this at `app_start` where there's not yet an `HttpContext`, thus `Request` and `Server` are not options.

This did the trick:

```
System.Web.HttpRuntime.BinDirectory
```

**Edit**

As of **.net core**, you can use `PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath` of nuget pkg `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions`, which resolves for any runtime.

Answer (score 16):

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin") ;
Application.StartupPath + "/bin";
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/bin";

//Note in Asp.net Core its little bit different
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
        IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
        public ValuesController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
            string applicationPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
            string wwwrootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        }
}
```

and many more that described in a [blog](http://www.asptricks.net/2015/06/application-current-folder-in-aspnet-c.html)

Comment: This was the only answer I could use effectively in a WebApi request. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Using the following snippet:

```
string strPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Server.MapPath("~/bin")
```

You can also use 
`Request.PhysicalApplicationPath`

Answer (score 2):

`HostingEnvironment.MapPath()` Vs `Server.MapPath()` Server.MapPath is used to map a physical location on webserver for asp.net. `String path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/myFolder/myFile.txt");` Server.MapPath specifies the relative or virtual path to map to a physical directory.

**sample:**

```
 string path=System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Files/ExamResult.rdlc");
```

For More Detail Visit This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/944267/5576498)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it