# Adding content files to and accessing content files from a web service

Tags: c#, web-services, output, asmx

I want to include an XML file in the bin directory of my web application/web service.  I've included the bin folder in my project in Visual Studio and added the file.  I set its Build Action to "Content" and Copy to Output Directory to "Copy Always".  When my code goes to find it, I use

```
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
if (!dir.EndsWith(@"\")) dir += @"\";
```

to get the directory and return it as `appPath`, where `appPath` is (unescaped version):

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\0c7655f\d4908928\assembly\dl3\5cf9fd67\fdc52284_ffa7d201\
```

then I append the file name of my XML file (where `string filename = "myXmlFile.xml"`) to read it:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(appPath + filename);
```

But I get an exception on that line of code, that it could not find my file.  I am handling for escaping of the slashes fine, so it is not that.  When I checked the physical directory that the path points to, it was not copied to that directory, and that is the cause of the exception.  So how do I get my file to get copied there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.applicationphysicalpath.aspx)

```
var dir = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "bin\\filename.xml")
```

See related question [how to get the application path in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298515/how-to-get-the-application-path-in-asp-net).

Comment: Actually - we later found that I shouldn't have been using `bin` for where my file should live, if we wanted to do any writes to it.  Any time you write from a web app or service to content files in folders under it, it resets the site - so any static global variables become cleared.  Just a note of caution for anyone that wants to follow my footsteps.  When we moved it to the same level as the site, everything was fine - so we just don't use `bin` in that path, anymore.  Cheers!