# server.mappath null

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HttpContext.Current.Server null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304532/httpcontext-current-server-null)

I have three projects in my ASP .NET solution:

- a class library
- a web application
- a windows service

I have a folder in my web application with an XML file. An XMLreader from class library function needs to be populated with this XML file. I have added this:

```
var reader = XmlReader.Create(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/TestDevice/Data.xml"), settings);
```

When this function is called from we application, It works.
When this function of class library is called from windows application, I get null reference at HttpContext.Current.Server because it is not available in windows application. I don't want to give hardcode path although that works for both windows and web application. Can I use some don't function to access files from different projects or any alternate of server.mappath. Please suggest solution

Thanks

Comment: Fourth time the same question asked by the same user in 2 days.

Comment: if this indeed is the fourth time you ask the question, please bother to learn to format code and lists.

Comment: Stop asking the same question and reply to your current ones http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304532/httpcontext-current-server-null or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310344/httpcontext-current-server-mappath-alternative-in-windows-application or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306992/file-path-using-c

Answer (score 9):

`System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` should do the trick.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx

> Gets the base directory that the
>   assembly resolver uses to probe for
>   assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

[HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath alternative in windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310344/httpcontext-current-server-mappath-alternative-in-windows-application)

[file path using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306992/file-path-using-c)

[HttpContext.Current.Server null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304532/httpcontext-current-server-null)

Asking the same basic question four different times isn't going to change the fact that you cannot use a Windows Service to access the web application path and the web app isn't going to know where your service is.

Use a configuration file to define where your data will be stored and provide the same info to both - or use some other storage for your data like a database which has a published location.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably to pass the path to the xml file into that function, rather than making the function itself clever enough to figure it out- then your web app could use the HttpContext method, and the Winforms app would use a regular path.  There is no equivalent of the MapPath method for WinForms or windows services.