# HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath alternative in windows application

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

what is alternative of "HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath" in Windows application, which is used in web application. What should I use in windows application to access a file.

[EDIT]
What is alternate of this in window application?

```
reader = XmlReader.Create(
            @"D:\EnviroTrack\EnviroTracker.Web\TestDevice\Data.xml", settings);
```

Please suggest

Comment: possible duplicate of [HttpContext.Current.Server null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304532/httpcontext-current-server-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the normal [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) methods. `MapPath` helps convert the virtual path to the physical path on the web server. There's no need for this conversion in winforms. You may be looking for [Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) which returns the location of the assembly being executed.

Edit - Your updated question should work on in a Winform.
[XmlReader.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162474.aspx) has quite a few overloads, one of them is `(string, XmlReaderSettings)`. This is the overload you're using in your question. You can use the same method, but different directory if you like.

```
reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Data.xml", settings);
```

To get the directory of the executing assembly, you can use [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx). So it could be something like this:

```
reader = XmlReader.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Data.xml", settings);
```

Comment: @DotnetSparrow - Updated. You can use the BaseDirectory property which will return the path of the executable. You can then add your `Data.xml` file relative to this path.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location` returns the `exe` or `dll` name , haven't tried this functionality in a while, so can't be certain about it.

`Application.StarupPath` might do the job.