# How to MapPath with RequestContext in WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, xsd

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx) says:

`HttpContext: Current is always null when accessed from within a WCF service. Use RequestContext instead.`

What I'm trying to do is load some XSD files in from my IIS hosted WCF service. Problem is, I can't figure out how to do a Server.MapPath() like I would in any old vanilla ASP.NET website, something like:

`HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(schemaUri);`

What would be the equivalent way using RequestContext in an IIS hosted WCF service?

The schemas are located in a "Schemas" directory at the root of the service application. They're referenced using a custom config section in the web.config like this:

```
<schemas>
    <add uri="~/Schemas/foo.xsd" xmlNamespace="http://foo.bar/types" />
</schemas>
```

And I was trying to load like this:

`var schemaUri = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(schema.Uri);`

Which works fine from within a normal ASP.NET website, just not an IIS hosted WCF service.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use [HostingEnvironment.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath.aspx).

Comment: Hoooo! Sweet! That even works in a UnitTest project! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: If you follow the link you will find the namespace for the HostingEnvironment class is System.Web.Hosting