# VS 2012 & IIS Express. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\MyPics\My.jpg'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

I am developing a Asp.Net MVC 4 application using VS 2012. The application when running in local is using the IIS Express as web server.I am facing issues in trying to access a file which is part of my solution. I have the following action method :

```
public FileContentResult GetImage()
        {
            byte[] imageByte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"/MyPics/My.jpg");
            string contentType = "image/jpeg";

            return File(imageByte, contentType);
        }
```

In the first line, I am getting the following error :

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\MyPics\My.jpg'
```

I know that the above path is not correct but I am not able to understand what path I should provide in order to solve this problem.

Regards
Pawan Mishra

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Server.MapPath() to get the actual directory like this:

```
byte[] imageByte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/MyPics/My.jpg"));
```

Some people advocate using HostingEnvironment.MapPath() instead: [What is the difference between Server.MapPath and HostingEnvironment.MapPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944219/what-is-the-difference-between-server-mappath-and-hostingenvironment-mappath)

Comment: Awesome, looked everywhere for this. Thnx!

Comment: This is a great way, just had to mention: HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath

Comment: @SharifYazdian Additionally, you can pass the current context as a parameter to, say, a shared method in a separate class where `HttpContext.Current` is not available, and use `context.Server.MapPath(...)`.