# HttpContext.Server seems to be null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following line of code in the constructor of a controller in my .NET MVC app.

```
  _mediaDir = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/media");
```

When the debugger hits this line it throws an exception.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in OBXCart.dll
```

I think HttpContext is null but I don't know why. Can anyone shed a little light on this?

Comment: Check this [First change exception](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HostingEnvironment.MapPath() instead. Please see my answer at [VS 2012 & IIS Express. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\MyPics\My.jpg'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863725/vs-2012-iis-express-could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-c-program-files-x86/15864084#15864084) and the link therein.

Comment: I ended up using `HostingEnvironement.MapPath()`, which fixed my issue on my local machine. I'm not sure if I didn't have other issue as well, but this got headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
_mediaDir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/media");
```