# Asp.Net cant find txt file using streamreader

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream, streamreader, reader

```
    string[] usernames;
    string[] password ;
    bool username;
    bool passok;
    bool match;
    string passinp;
    string userinp;

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        StreamReader SrUs = new StreamReader("Usernames.txt");
        StreamReader SrPass = new StreamReader("Password.txt");
        int i = 0;
        while(!SrUs.EndOfStream)
        {
            usernames[i] = SrUs.ReadLine();
        }
        i = 0;
        while(SrPass.EndOfStream)
        {
            password[i] = SrPass.ReadLine();
        }

        if (txt_pass.Text != "" && txt_username.Text != "")
        {
            passinp = txt_pass.Text;
            userinp = txt_username.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            Label3.Text = "Missing information";
        }

        int j = 0;
        for(i = 0;i < usernames.Length;i++)
        {
            if(usernames[i] == userinp)
            {
                username = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(j = 0 ; j < password.Length;j++)
        {
            if(password[j]==passinp)
            {
                passok = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        if(username && passok && i == j)
        {
            Label3.Text = "Logon Correct";
        }
        else
        {
            Label3.Text = "Logon Incorect";
        }
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

So when I run this it gives me an error that it can't find txt file, is it same in asp.net and in windows form app use of streamreader, I put txt files inside bin and root folder but again it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET you can't use system directories directly. So you have to use `Server.MapPath("~/")` to get the Root Directory Path of your application.

You can use like this

```
string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/") + "Usernames.txt";
StreamReader SrUs = new StreamReader(FilePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you have no idea where the current DLLs are actually being executed. You have guessed the "bin" directory.

Environment.CurrentDirectory is probably your best bet 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx

or see this question on httpcontexts
[How do I get the current directory in a web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236166/how-do-i-get-the-current-directory-in-a-web-service)

TBH storing usernames and passwords in text files inside a website working directory is probably a bad idea. Consider a fixed directory store outside of C:\inetpub\ or use ADFS or a database

DO NOT HOMEBAKE YOUR OWN SECURITY CODE

Comment: Im just making really simple programing project for my class . If I was doing this for somebody or for my personal use then I would probably use sql or import database from acces or something .

Comment: If you are a student then fine; if you are a teacher - this is bad.

Its amazing what things students learn by example - and this is a horrible example.