# c# WebService uses a .rec file

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm developing a c# webservice that needs to use a .rec file (a recognizer, check the PS) in order to recognize written characters and return a string.

There is a method given in a dll, it's :

```
void ICR_SelectRecognizer(int Session, string RecFile);
```

the string is the RecFile's path. This function doesn't seem to find the .rec file eventhough the path is correct :

```
ICR_SelectRecognizer(Session, Server.MapPath("~/eurodigit.rec"));
```

How can I fix this?

PS

1. From the recogniform web site: Platform: the engine is packaged in DLL format. For each content type (American Digit, European Digits, Uppercase Alpha, Lowercase Alpha, Mixed Alpha, etc...) is required a separate .REC file. The full engine size is less than 5 MB.
2. Everything seems to work just fine when i use a windows form, but the web service always returns a null string, i take it as the web service doesn't find the recognizer?

Comment: Welcome!  Please don't type in one large paragraph.  I have tidied it for you.  Wishing you well

Comment: Did you set the file's property to be Compile: _none_; Copy: _always_?

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236166/how-do-i-get-the-current-directory-in-a-web-service - you can also use the debugger to check the path.

Comment: Assuming the web service is hosted in IIS, does the IIS configured [app pool identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) have the necessary permissions to read your .rec file ?

Comment: @MickyD Yes, still doesn't work

Comment: @Subbu I just installed the IIS manager after i read your reply and the defaultAppPool shows the error message "Application  pools cannot be started unless the windows activation service (was) is running".

Comment: @Subbu I fixed the ISS Pool problem, i gave the ISS APPPOOL/DefaultAppPool the permission to read, yet it's still not working