# C# MVC Core Print Excel file using Process(), PDF works fine but Excel keep loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, printing, processstartinfo

I am trying to print Excel(.xlsx) file via my web application by clicking a button.
Everything works fine on my local, however when I upload to IIS, the moment I click the button. The page will just keep loading.

```
                string destinationFileWord = filePath;

                Process print = new Process();
                print.StartInfo.FileName = destinationFileWord;
                print.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

                print.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                print.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                print.StartInfo.Verb = "PrintTo";

                print.StartInfo.Arguments = Utility.GetAppSettings("PrinterSettings", "Address1");
                print.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(destinationFileWord);
                print.Start();

                if (print.HasExited == false)
                {
                    print.WaitForExit(5000);

                }
```

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the document stored in IIS working directory or in a more traditional such as network drive?

Comment: @mr.coffee thanks for ur reply. it is stored in IIS Working directory.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is mostly likely the directory mapping. On the server you need to use something like this to get the current working directory.

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/")
```

There are a number of other methods posted in this SO post:

[How do I get the current directory in a web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236166/how-do-i-get-the-current-directory-in-a-web-service)

EDIT

For .NET Core you need to use IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath:

[How to get root directory of project in asp.net core. Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() doesn't seem to work correctly on a mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43709657/how-to-get-root-directory-of-project-in-asp-net-core-directory-getcurrentdirect)

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your reply. 
But I dont think thats the problem, because I actually had another function to print PDF and it works.

What I am trying to say is that there are no problem with finding the filePath or fileName.

Comment: HI. Turns out it was because of Microsoft Excel, if I change the default app to open .XLSX to LibreOffice then it works. Any idea what might be the probleM